# SharePoint Online Site inherit security group from hubsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, pnp-powershell

Is there a PowerShell script/cmdlet (pnp/spo) to inherit securitysettings from hubsite?

All sites linked to hubsite https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing should have the same permission settings as the hubsite.

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. From the offical docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites

> Hub sites do not alter an associated site's permissions.

For permission inheritance between hub site and associated sites, You can open a new post about it in [userVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration).